# How to create Custom Directive by composing multiple directives in spray

Tags: scala, spray

I would like to write a custom directive for all get, post,put and delete requests, because all requests needs authorization. To keep code DRY, I want to abstract those boilerplate(I have to authorize more than 100 requests). I could handle all Get Requests as follows

```
def method1 = Try("hi")       // controller methods
def method2 = Try("hello")

 path("getData1") {
    handleGetRequest(method1)
  }
  path("getData2") {
    handleGetRequest(method2)
  }


  def customGetDirective: Directive0 = {
    headerValueByName("token").flatMap { token =>
      authorize(checkAuthorization(token, ""))
      get.hflatMap {x=>
        respondWithMediaType(`application/json`)
      }
    }
  }

  def handleGetRequest(fn: => Try[_]) = {
    customGetDirective { ctx=>
    val result = fn
    val json = //result can be coverted to json
    ctx.complete(json)
    }
  }
```

I want to write a similar Generic directive for POST request, so that I could use

```
  path("postData1") {
    handlePostRequest(saveToDb)
  }

    def handlePostRequest(fn: => Try[_]) = {
    customPostDirective { (ctx, JsonData)=>
    //.......
    ctx.complete(json)
    }
  }
```

> but, I dont know how to get RequestContext and JsonData as tuple

```
  I can write  like this,
  entity(as[String]) { jsonData => 
    customPostDirective{ ctx=>
  }
  }
```

If I get a tuple it will be more useful. 
Thank you.

Comment: Just a side note, wouldn't it be just easier to wrap everything in `authorize` directive? Like so: `val xx: Route = authorize(x => true) {
    path("abc") {
      complete("a")
    } ~
      path("def") {
        complete("b")
      }
  }`

Comment: @ lpiepiora, For Post, Put and Delete request I need Parameter directive also. and I need two different types of authorization Post methods.

Comment: Still, maybe I'm missing something but you can nest parameters under authorization, or do you mean you need them for authorization. Anyway I still don't see why you need tuple propagated to inner route directives.

Comment: @ lpiepiora, GET request don't need all the directives as POST. and for some post request I need extra directive. If I put authorize at top, I need to create separate routes for all GET, and POST requests. Currently I have my routes as, `path("abc") { post{save} ~ get { getAll} }`. In addition to authorize, I want to apply extra directive only to post request, and I don't want to apply that to get.

Comment: Try `customPostDirective { case(ctx, JsonData)=>...`